# How is the correct for for saying someone still didn't did something?

Tags: past-tense

I have an [VSCode extension](https://github.com/felipecaputo/git-project-manager), and when someone tries to open the recent opened projects list, if he didn't used the extension to open any projects, it gives the user the following message:

> It seems you didn't opened any project using Git Project Manager yet

And a user opened an [issue](https://github.com/felipecaputo/git-project-manager/issues/56) asking if the correct way to write that message would be:

> It seems you haven't opened any projects ...

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "did" as an auxiliary always takes an infinitive, the present form of a verb.

So the phrase "didn't opened" is not correct; it should be "didn't open".

You can say either "It seems you didn't open....." or "It seems you haven't opened..........".